# It is possible to use the TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate API of tess4J without needing to create physical files?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, bufferedimage, tess4j, leptonica

I am using the Tesseract Java API (tess4J) to convert Tiff images to PDFs.

This works nicely, but I am forced to write both the source Tiff image and the output PDF to local filestore as actual physical files in order to use the `TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate` API.

Please note the following in the code snippet below: -

1. The input Tiff is originally a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, but I have to write it to a physical file (sourceTiffFile is a File object).
2. I must specify a file path for the output (pdfFullFilepath is a String representing an absolute path for the new PDF file).

   ```
       try {
           ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "tiff", sourceTiffFile);
       } catch (Exception ioe) {
           //handling code...
       }

       TessResultRenderer renderer = TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate(pdfFullFilepath, dataPath, 0);
       TessAPI1.TessResultRendererInsert(renderer, TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate(pdfFullFilepath, dataPath, 0));
       int result = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(handle, sourceTiffFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, 0, renderer);
   ```

I would really like to avoid creating physical files, but am not sure if it is possible with this API. Ideally, I would like to pass the Tiff as a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` or a byte array and receive the output PDF as a byte array.

Any suggestions would be most welcome as always. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `ProcessPage` API method a `Pix`, which can be converted from a `BufferedImage`, but the output will still be a physical file. Tesseract API dictates that.

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessapi/4.0.0/a01625.html

http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-4.4/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1.html

For ex:

```
int result = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPage(handle, LeptUtils.convertImageToPix(bufferedImage), page_index, "input file name", null, 0, renderer);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this solution. Would you mind clarifying a little further? Are you suggestion that I call TessBaseAPI.ProcessPage(...) method and that I pass Pix of my image into that call?